# How do I get the size of a directory in C?

Tags: c, size, posix, directory

Is there a POSIX function that will give me the size of a directory (including all sub-folders), roughly equivalent to "`du -s somepath`"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$ man nftw
```

> **NAME**
>
> `ftw`, `nftw` - file tree walk
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `ftw()` walks through the directory tree
>   that is located under the directory
>   dirpath, and calls `fn()` once for  each
>   entry  in  the  tree.   By default, 
>   directories  are  handled before the
>   files and subdirectories they contain
>   (pre-order traversal).
>
> **CONFORMING TO**
>
> POSIX.1-2001, SVr4, SUSv1.

### Simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static unsigned int total = 0;

int sum(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag) {
    total += sb->st_size;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (!argv[1] || access(argv[1], R_OK)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (ftw(argv[1], &sum, 1)) {
        perror("ftw");
        return 2;
    }
    printf("%s: %u\n", argv[1], total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are in a multi-threaded environment, do not use this approach.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23200405/717274) for an explanation.

Comment: Better create a separate function instead of using main args.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ready-made function, so you will have to make your own. You may look at the source code of the GNU implemenation of du as an example (see http://www.gnu.org/prep/ftp.html for a list of places to download from). It is in the `coreutils` package.

The crucial Posix calls are probably `opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir`, and `stat`.

Comment: And lstat() - if you want to distinguish between symlinks and the files or directories at the far end of the link.  Also ftw/nftw.

Answer (score -2):

Result in bytes:

```
du -sb | grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+'
```

Comment: This is neither C nor a full answer.